# UWP StorageFile Access Denied in LocalFolder in Release build

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I am trying to write a very simple program that reads a txt file when it starts. The file is in "ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder", as it is supposed to be something I can access without explicitly telling the user. However, after I try to check the existence of and to create the file, I receive a access denied exception at 'file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()' at the 2nd line of the second method.

The StorageFile object is passed from the checking process, so that I think I am able to avoid the situation where two objects try to open the same file. However, the problem persists.

```
    public async Task<StorageFile> checkConfig()
    {
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        if (await localFolder.TryGetItemAsync("ifthen.txt") != null)
            return await localFolder.GetFileAsync("ifthen.txt");
        else
            return await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("ifthen.txt");

    }
    public async void load()
    {
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await checkConfig();
        using (var input = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        using (var dataReader = new StreamReader(input))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Furthermore, the problem only occurs in Release Build. Debug Build always works fine, regardless of whether the file exists or not before launching the program.

Comment: Small refactoring:
Instead `if - else` use `return await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("ifthen.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);`

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. As @MakeMakeluv said, you can use `return await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("ifthen.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);` instead of your `checkConfig` method. If you still have problem, please share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue as you, did you ever solve it?